# How much allocated space for log/data is too much? (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, relational-database

This is a somewhat unusual question...

Is there such a thing as too big of an allocation for data and log files for SQL Server?

Please note, that I am **NOT** talking about running out of space.

Let's assume for the moment that there is infinite storage, but limited I/O throughput. Does the size of the unfilled portions of data and log files the server is accessing matter for performance? For example, if I have a log file for tempdb that only ever fills up to ~5mb, but have a terabyte allocated to it, would the I/O operations accessing this log complete faster if I reduced allocation to 10mb?

Comment: Size of space is a concern if it's too little, or if the drive access time really sucks it will be a bottle neck to write to.

Comment: I'm explicitly assuming here that "too little" isn't a problem, so there is no file growth. Are you saying that it's faster to write to this log if it's smaller? (again, provided that you never write so much that it forces autogrowth to kick in)

Comment: Speed to write based on bandwidth & drive technology.

Answer (score 1):

No, allocated size will not affect perfomance. Perfomance is affected only on file growth.